# Getting rid of magic numbers in php array

Tags: php, arrays, magic-numbers

Here's my code

```
$q->addNotInCondition('`t`.`id`', array(0, 1, 2));
```

I want to remove magic numbers in array. Is there a special way to do this or just define 0 , 1 and 2 ?

Is this correct?

```
const ONE= 4;
const TWO= 2;
const THREE= 4;

$q->addNotInCondition('`t`.`id`', array(ONE, TWO, THREE));
```

Comment: what is the meaning of magic numbers? also, please describe your problem more

Comment: @sachinkumaraliyanage machan, A magic number is a direct usage of a number in the code. have to getting rid of it and want to know there is specific way to do.

Comment: why do you care about doing this, in this specific case? What are you trying to achieve? Do you want these values to come from user input instead? Or you just want to label them and give them meaning?

Comment: @ADyson yes, It's some thing like labeling.

Comment: well ok you could use constants yes, or maybe fetch them from an associative array. There are probably a few ways to do it, in fact. None is "right" or "wrong" really, as long as it helps you to improve your code in a way you find useful.